# laravel Joins to get data from multiple tables and multiple records in a single column

Tags: mysql, laravel

i have following tables in mysql
**student**
id | client_id | givenname |surname | email |  dob | agent_id

**programs**

id | program_name | program_detail | country_id | province_id

**application**

id  | applicant_id | program_id | school_id  | country_id  | intake_id

**application_statues**

id  | application_id     | status | remarks

i want to get information in the following format

Sr. No |Given Name| Surname| Email| Date of Birth|  Applications|   Submission Date|    Status|
1 | satnam| Singh|  satnam@gmail.com| 10-10-2002| BCA, DCA,  BBA| 10-10-2022| Approved, Approved, Approved|

a single student have multiple applications, i want to show all applications name in applications column. i just want to concatenate in silgle column
i have tried the following code.. but no proper result ..

```
 $data = DB::table('students')
                 ->leftJoin('applications', 'applications.applicant_id', '=', 'students.id')
                 ->leftJoin('programs', 'programs.id', '=', 'applications.program_id')
                 ->leftJoin('application_statuses', 'application_statuses.application_id', '=', 'applications.id')
                 ->leftJoin('program_intakes', 'program_intakes.program_id', '=', 'programs.id')
                 ->where("students.agent_id", auth()->user()->id)
                 ->select('students.*', 'students.id as sid', 'applications.program_id', 'applications.created_at as submitted_at', 'programs.program_name', 'application_statuses.*')
                 ->selectRaw('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                     CONCAT(\'{"application_name": "\', programs.program_name, \'",
                     "intake_year": "\', program_intakes.intake_year, \'"
                     }\')
                 ) FROM program_intakes WHERE program_intakes.program_id = applications.program_id) as application_detail')
                 ->groupBy('students.id', 'students.givenname', 'students.client_id', 'students.surname', 'students.email', 'students.dob', 'applications.program_id', 'applications.created_at', 'programs.program_name', 'application_statuses.*')
                 ->latest('application_statuses.created_at')
                 ->get();
```

all suggestions are welcome.. thanx in advanced

Sr. No |Given Name| Surname| Email| Date of Birth|  Applications|   Submission Date|    Status|
1 | satnam| Singh|  satnam@gmail.com| 10-10-2002| BCA, DCA,  BBA| 10-10-2022| Approved, Approved, Approved|

a single student have multiple applications, i want to show all applications name in applications column. i just want to concatenate in silgle column
i have tried the following code.. but no proper result ..

```
 $data = DB::table('students')
                 ->leftJoin('applications', 'applications.applicant_id', '=', 'students.id')
                 ->leftJoin('programs', 'programs.id', '=', 'applications.program_id')
                 ->leftJoin('application_statuses', 'application_statuses.application_id', '=', 'applications.id')
                 ->leftJoin('program_intakes', 'program_intakes.program_id', '=', 'programs.id')
                 ->where("students.agent_id", auth()->user()->id)
                 ->select('students.*', 'students.id as sid', 'applications.program_id', 'applications.created_at as submitted_at', 'programs.program_name', 'application_statuses.*')
                 ->selectRaw('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
                     CONCAT(\'{"application_name": "\', programs.program_name, \'",
                     "intake_year": "\', program_intakes.intake_year, \'"
                     }\')
                 ) FROM program_intakes WHERE program_intakes.program_id = applications.program_id) as application_detail')
                 ->groupBy('students.id', 'students.givenname', 'students.client_id', 'students.surname', 'students.email', 'students.dob', 'applications.program_id', 'applications.created_at', 'programs.program_name', 'application_statuses.*')
                 ->latest('application_statuses.created_at')
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do this

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'students';

    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Application::class, 'applicant_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Application extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'applications';

    public function program()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Program::class, 'program_id', 'id');
    }

    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ApplicationStatus::class, 'application_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Program extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'programs';
}

class ApplicationStatus extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'application_statuses';
}
```

you can retrieve the data in the desired format using Eloquent relationships

```php
$students = Student::where('agent_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->with(['applications.program', 'applications.statuses'])
    ->get();

$result = [];

foreach ($students as $student) {
    $applications = $student->applications->map(function ($application) {
        return $application->program->program_name;
    })->implode(', ');

    $statuses = $student->applications->map(function ($application) {
        return $application->statuses->isEmpty() ? 'N/A' : $application->statuses->first()->status;
    })->implode(', ');

    $result[] = [
        'Sr. No' => count($result) + 1,
        'Given Name' => $student->givenname,
        'Surname' => $student->surname,
        'Email' => $student->email,
        'Date of Birth' => $student->dob,
        'Applications' => $applications,
        'Submission Date' => $student->submitted_at,
        'Status' => $statuses,
    ];
}

// Now $result contains the data in the desired format
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException
Call to undefined relationship [applications] on model [App\Models\Student\Student].

Comment: The error message indicates that Laravel is unable to find a relationship named "applications" on the "Student" model. This usually happens when the relationship is not defined correctly. please refer to the models i posted above